# How to swap Picture

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, timer, picturebox

Hi I have a problem how to a swap picture in my picture box for 
EX: pictuebox1 display pic1 then pictuebox 2 display pic2
then they swap pics and then picturebox1 display pic2 and  and picturebox2 display pic3 and then they swap again. How do I do that? Its breaking my head if anyone could help me I be very thankful.

```
    string[] picture = {
                       @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die1.jpg",
                       @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die2.jpg",
                         @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die3.jpg",
                           @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die4.jpg",
                             @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die5.jpg",
                                @"ImageResource\Die_Images\die6.jpg"};
    int index = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
        if (index >= picture.Length)
            index = 1;
        else

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\die{0}.jpg", index);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            if (index >= picture.Length)
                index = 0;
            else
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"ImageResource\Die_Images\die{0}.jpg", index);
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: you need to put brackets around if/else statements that have more than a single line in them

Comment: Where do you set the timers interval? and is this winforms/wpf

Comment: What to you meant by swap? both picture boxes should interchange its images?

Comment: You should set pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
in the Click handler for example... it's redundant to set at every tick. Actually I don't really got this swapping mechanism... could you describe it more precisely?

Comment: Box1 pic1 Box2 pic2 now they swap Box1 pic2 Box2 pic1... and the repeat with Box1 pic2 and box2 pic3 and they swap Box1 pic3 Box2 Pic2 and etc.. if u get me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking at, but give a try.

```
private int operationState = 0; 

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(operationState)
    {
        case 0://Next image
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picture[index];
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = picture[index + 1];

            index++;
            if (index >= (picture.Length - 1))
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1://Swap
        {
            string tempLocation =  pictureBox1.ImageLocation;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = pictureBox2.ImageLocation;
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = tempLocation;
            break;
        }
    }

    operationState = (++operationState) % 2;
}
```

I removed the `SizeMode` setting code from Tick event, you can do it somewhere else only once.